# Is it possible to dynamically clone an Adobe Edge animation Symbol and manipulate each clone individually?

Tags: adobe-edge

I have a web page containing an Adobe Edge animation. The animation contains a single stage and a single symbol. I want to use the symbol element as a button.

The problem is I need multiple identical buttons, each behaving the same way visually, but positioned differently. Is there a way to programmatically (via JavaScript) "clone" a symbol such that multiple copies appear on the stage dynamically?

Comment: I've found the solution to this problem here:

http://chrisgannon.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/binding-clicks-to-dynamic-symbols-in-adobe-edge/

Answer (score -1):

No need to use Javascript. That's what symbols are there for.

Say you have a single symbol named "button".

You can create on the Stage as many as you want, and position them differently, by dragging the symbol on the stage multiple times (from the Library > Symbols panel on the right).
This way you create symbol's instances.

Then all you have to do is to bind click events not on the symbol (that way all the buttons will do the same thing, not wanted) but on the symbol instances on the stage.

Open the Code window (Window > Code) and select the stage.

Click on the plus button next to Stage, then on Elements and you will see a list with all your buttons.

Handle the click event on the button as you like.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Is there a way to programmatically clone a symbol? I want to have 100+ particles rotating around the screen and can't be dragging and dropping 100 copies.

Comment: Sure. Sorry I didn't understand the scenario.